# shopware home page shows the below error after install the shopware

Tags: shopware

I have install the shopware after completed the insatllation frontend show the below error. Please help how to fix the issue.

Oops! An error has occurred!

The following notes should help you.

An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT page.id, page.description, page.link, page.target, page.parentID, groups.key as `group`, mapping.key as mapping FROM s_cms_static page LEFT JOIN s_cms_static_groups groups ON groups.active = 1 LEFT JOIN s_cms_static_groups mapping ON groups.mapping_id = mapping.id LEFT JOIN s_core_shop_pages shops ON groups.id = shops.group_id AND shops.shop_id = ? WHERE (groups.active = 1) AND (page.active = 1) AND (CONCAT('|', page.grouping, '|') LIKE CONCAT('%|', groups.key, '|%')) AND ((mapping.id IS NULL OR shops.shop_id IS NOT NULL)) AND ((mapping.id IS NULL OR mapping.active=1)) AND ((page.shop_ids IS NULL OR page.shop_ids LIKE ?)) ORDER BY parentID ASC, mapping.key ASC, page.position ASC, page.description ASC' with params [1, "%|1|%"]: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'groups ON groups.active = 1 LEFT JOIN s_cms_static_groups mapping ON groups.mapp' at line 1 in vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php on line 131

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue might be caused by msql 8. Please have a look at this pull-request: https://github.com/shopware/shopware/commit/f23aaf4ea571d4bae95b76a06bc1d673b4536931

I strongly recomment using shopware 5.5 (since the pull request is merged with this version) or try mariadb/an older mysql version.